# php fetch database, displaying them customized.

Tags: php, jquery

During fetching data from database with **$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from MY_table**, it display 100 columns at a time. my main aim is to display 10 columns at a time, with the help of next and previous buttons user gonna read remaining. is it possible to do with Javascript , or AJAX, or PHP alone.

Comment: By columns you mean rows?

Comment: AJAX *is* Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you're looking for is 'pagination'. You can divide your query results into pages. PHP can fetch a part of the query results, and you can click on a button or link to fetch the next page. That next page can be loaded by an entire page refresh, or by Ajax. In either case, PHP fetches the next results and returns them.

9lessons.info has a [tutorial on this exact same topic](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html). Well, more a bunch of snippets than a tutorial, but still..

If you're just starting: forget about Ajax at first. Start with reading about the `LIMIT` clause in MySQL. It allows you to query a subresult of the query, by limiting the returned rows to a specific range.

You can pass a page (or a range) in the url, so when you click 'Next page', you can just call PHP again with `?page=2` or something in the url. Based on that number, you can query a different range of rows.

The last step is to update only a part of the page using Ajax instead of doing a full page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit to your sql query to do this

```
$start = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from MY_table limit ".$start.", 10");
```

initially $start will be 0 the change the $start variable as per your prev next ..